# Boost converter driving permanent electromagnet

Tags: power-supply, power

I am using a DC to DC boost converter to drive a 12 volt 1.2 ampere permanent electromagnet.  It is  3.7 volt 25 c lithium battery ramped to 12 VDC. It seems to "bog down" even though the rated current is 5 amps and output voltage crashes. Are protection circuits kicking in?  Is there any way to bypass this? Two 3.7 VDC batteries in series still do same thing.  A 12 VDC 3 ampere wall wart powers thr electromagnet just fine.

Comment: You are looking for 14.4 W of output power.  With 3.7 V input voltage you would need an input current of around 5A (depending on boost efficiency).  Depending on the internal impedance of the battery, state of charge, and impedance of the connections to the converter you may be tripping the input current limit.  We have no way to know without datasheets for your battery, the boost converter, and a schematic and photo of your setup.  Have you measured Vin at the converter during the dropout?

Comment: Cctvdiagrsm, boost converter link, battery link all useful. | Run converter on no load then add increasing Rload and note Vout. | Is there a cap across inductor? | Diagram!

Comment: @ATCSVOL Cctvdiagrsm?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson OnvPhonevSorevthumb. IsAs
SumesItssComprehensible :-)

Comment: I have finally tracked down the files.  Here they are.  I also should note that i only need the permanent Electromagnet to be power for 2-3 seconds to release its attracted object. (Battery)https://imgur.com/oOdLQue (Converter)https://imgur.com/z9FyEy2 (circuit)https://imgur.com/wxmRo7w